# Video is not being loaded in page control in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xib, avplayer

I am implmenting pages control, and in each page video will be playing, but i had made it with using xibs, load each video in each xib, only the first video is being get played, rest all videos not getting played, showing as blank screen.

Main Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadScrollView()
}

func loadScrollView() {
    let pageCount : CGFloat = 3.0

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * pageCount, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    pageController.numberOfPages = Int(pageCount)

    let v1 = Video1.instanceFromNib() // xib with video 1
    let v2 = Video2.instanceFromNib() // xib with video 2
    let v3 = Video3.instanceFromNib() // xib with video 3

    var videoClassArray  = [v1,v2,v3] as [UIView]

    for i in 0..<Int(pageCount) {
        print(self.scrollView.frame.size.width)
        var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height))
        view = videoClassArray[i]
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
    }
}


//MARK: UIScrollView Delegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
    // content offset - tells by how much the scroll view has scrolled.
    let pageNumber = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth / 50) / viewWidth) + 1
    pageController.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}


//MARK: Page tap action
func pageChanged() {
    let pageNumber = pageController.currentPage
    var frame = scrollView.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(pageNumber)
    frame.origin.y = 0
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

The above is the view controller where im loading the xibs into various views.And the xib code is in the below.

```
class Video1: UIView {

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "Video1", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
var videoName = "BoardSetup_1"

@IBOutlet weak var baseView: UIView!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension: "mp4")

    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player?.isMuted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    playerLayer.bounds = self.layer.bounds

    playerLayer.frame = baseView.frame
    baseView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    baseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    player?.play()


    //loop video
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player.play()
        }
    })


}
}
```

The above code is for xib with loading the videos , the code is same for the rest xibs, so mentioning only 1 xib.
**The issue im facing while loading the xib only the video will be get played in first view and in rest view its showing as blank screen.**

Answer (score 0):

Why not use should use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) for pagination? It's possible to use UIScrollView but then you need to implement the page recycling yourself otherwise you end up wasting a lot of memory.